# Unable to run redis as a daemon ... ubuntu server, redis 2.6.0

Tags: ubuntu, redis

Ack, this should be doable...

I have redis 2.6 installed, and it works fine if I kick it from a prompt. listens, is accessible and all that.

When I use the steps here:
http://ijonas.com/software-development/nosql/412/

to run it as a daemon... there are no untoward symptoms... the command:

sudo /etc/init.d/redis-server start

appears to work... but redis-server is not in the ps-aux list, and it is not listening on a port... it isn't running!

Nothing is logged... I changed the log level in the conf to verbose... zero in the log.

How to trace / solve?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you really try to download a 2.2 configuration file to be run against a Redis 2.6 server?

Comment: Yes, it would appear I did!  OK, I will review that side of the setup later today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didier is correct: The 2.2 config will not work with 2.6. A diff of the two configs shows very little has changed, but it is clearly enough.

On the one hand, I want to say "can't redis at least log what it didn't like in the config instead of shutting down silently?"

But I know, I know. What do I expect from FOSS? Redis is a gift. Even with the hassle and confusion, it is a gift.

And I am grateful.